# Multiversion API implementation

Tags: haskell

If I have library which implements API to some REST service  (in several modules: types+API calls+JSON instances...), what is the best (and convenient?) way to implement support for new API (version 2)? To create totally new library? But mostly code is the same, there are some breaking changes in JSON instances, API calls are the same, types mostly are the same. In this case any bug in common code must be "fixed" twice: in both libraries (also this involves tests modification in both libraries). How to "replace" only instances? Such flexible module modification is possible in ML and in F#, but I didn't find a way to do it in Haskell: importing of type only, w/o its instances and recreate for it new instance leads to error about duplicated instance (although instances are not exported and imported). So, what is the right and best was to create new API without big repeat of code? PS. Client will use both versions together

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a bit more information about the dependencies, what the changes are, what does _not_ change, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a use case of [backpack](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Backpack). Separate the types and instances that change between the two versions in one library for each version, and write the rest of the project against the common interface, which you can instantiate twice, similarly to ML functors.

If you don't want to duplicate the type declarations, I'm not certain it would work well, but maybe you can declare  types with a phantom parameter of kind `Version` in a common library:

```
data Version = V1 | V2

data MyData (v :: Version) = ...
data MyData2 (v :: Version) = C X Y (MyData v) | ...
```

and have two libraries declaring orphan instances for `MyData V1` and `MyData V2` respectively.

> importing of type only, w/o its instances

Instances are always exported and cannot be hidden, that's how Haskell's typeclass system works to ensure coherence (to the extent possible). My suggestion above introduces instances for two disjoint types `MyData V1`, `MyData V2`, while making it possible to freely coerce from one to the other.